# Calling showSettingsDialog() on the Google Drive SDK throws a Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to share a file in my Google Drive application to Google Plus via Javascript.

I followed the example code at this page: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing#add_the_dialog_script

I registered my app to the Google Drive SDK, I verified my app's URL with the Webmaster Tools (not sure that was necessary, but just in case) and put this code after the page load:

```
  var clientId = 'GOOGLE DRIVE SDK CLIENT ID';
  var apiKey = 'MY API KEY';

  var scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'];

  var access_token = ''; // Set after access is granted

  var share_client; // Set after access is grated

  function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
  }

  function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
  }

  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      init = function() {
          share_client = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient('756276963659');
      }
      gapi.load('drive-share', init);
    } else {
        console.log("error"); 
    }
  }

  function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
  }
```

A button calls handleAuthClick while handleClientLoad is called upon page load by:

```
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

Then to share an item:

```
  if (isShareEnabled()){
    share_client.setItemIds([image.fileID]);
    share_client.showSettingsDialog();
  }
```

That's when a window appears with the text "Loading..." and a spinning icon stays on the screen for a few seconds and then the alert message "Sorry, sharing is unavailable at this time. Please try again later." appears.

By looking at the Javascript console:

```
Uncaught Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12 2956664786-v2-doclist_share.js:453
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

Tested on Chrome 21 and Firefox 14, same problem.

Is this just a temporary issue or am I doing something wrong?

edit: I've also tried to use my Client ID for web applications instead of the Client ID for Google Drive SDK, same result.

edit2: the "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options" seems more like a warning, whereas "Uncaught Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12 2956664786-v2-doclist_share.js:453" stops the execution. DOM Exception 12 is a syntax error, e.g. a property has been mis-set.

Page: http://pierotofy.it/test/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure of 2 things:

- The "open with" URL that you have setup in your Google Drive SDK settings in the Google APIs Console has to have the same domain that the page where you are using the sharing dialog.
- Currently you alos need your application to be *installed* on your Google Drive for the embeddable widget to work. We are currently working on removing this restriction as it does not always make sense since we launched v2 of the API.

Comment: I double checked the Open URL field and it's the same as the URL that the page is running.

Comment: Is this online somewhere I could look at?

Comment: Mhh i don't see an issue with your code could you try setting the open-with URL to be the same as your website (http://pierotofy.it/test) Could you also set your OAuth 2 (under API Access in the APIs Console) redirect URI to be the same?

Comment: Tried, doesn't seem to work. As I pointed out in one of my edits, it really seems that the javascript code that is loaded during gapi.load('drive-share', init); contains an error and causes the execution to stop. Is there an example running on Google's site that I could look at?

Comment: OK actually yes we also use the feature on the Sample app that we provide called DrEdit. It takes a while to deploy though. I have it deployed and the Sharing Dialog is not working as well actually. So I think we might have a bug (or outage) on this. I'm letting our engineering team know and I'll let you know when I hear back! Sorry about that!

Comment: By the way the sample app can be seen deployed here: https://dredit-java.appspot.com/

Comment: Thank you for your help! Much appreciate.

Comment: So there is one thing that came up when discussing with the eng team: Currently you will have to "install" the application in roder for the embeddable sahring widget to work (right now it's a bit of a pain to instal an app sice you'll have to create a Chrome Web Store listing and install the app...). We are trying to remove this requirement we hope that we can get it in prod by wednesday (finger crossed). (There might be some other issues as well but we are still invstigating)

Comment: It is confirmed by our engineering team that the error that you are seeing is happening because right now, installation of your application on your Drive is mandatory to have the sharing widget work. We are working on removing this requirement. I'll update you when/if I have an ETA. Updating my answer too :)