# Google Drive SDK JavaScript file sharing dialog gives "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use the Google SDK file sharing dialog using the Javascript code described here: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing

I have an API key set up and have configured the Google Drive SDK panel as well: https://code.google.com/apis/console/

I can successfully list files stored on Google Drive using the API key and JavaScript but the sharing code does not work. A dialog that only contains a loading spinner appears and then it says "Sorry, sharing is unavailable at this time." and the Chrome Javascript console contains the error "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options" in Chrome. In Firefox, I get the error:

Error: Error: Permission denied to access property '_EmailAc_create'
Source File: docs.google.com/static/doclist/client/js/1880332762-v2-doclist_share__en_gb.js
Line: 470

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as nobody has been able to give you any advice at all, let me give you some low quality advice at least.

X-Frame-Options are used to prevent clickjacking attacks against an entire server by disallowing any pages with the specified header to be iframed. As far as I know google chrome lifts this restriction when the specified app is installed as a chrome web application, so probably your accompying web app isn't configured properly.

---

Additionally from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081816/calling-showsettingsdialog-on-the-google-drive-sdk-throws-a-refused-to-display?rq=1) it could also have to do with your settings in the console apparently:

> You need to make sure of 2 things:
>
> 1. The "open with" URL that you have setup in your Google Drive SDK
>      settings in the Google APIs Console has to have the same domain that
>      the page where you are using the sharing dialog.
> 2. Currently you alos
>      need your application to be installed on your Google Drive for the
>      embeddable widget to work.

Comment: in the end it was a trailing slash in my "open with" URL that was doing me in.  Blargh!