# Can't get Google Drive API share dialog to work when signed into multiple accounts

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm having a JS error when opening a share dialog in a Javascript application using the Google Drive API. The error is: Uncaught Error: Syntax Error: DOM Exception 12.

However, the sharing dialog works fine when I log out of all Google accounts and then log into just one account. As soon as I log into a second account in a new tab, the sharing dialog no longer works and fails with the above error.

This is very similar to [Calling showSettingsDialog() on the Google Drive SDK throws a Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081816/calling-showsettingsdialog-on-the-google-drive-sdk-throws-a-refused-to-display). However, I have done the debugging shown in the accepted response to no avail, namely:

- The "open with" URL that you have setup in your Google Drive SDK settings in the Google APIs Console has to have the same domain that the page where you are using the sharing dialog.
- Currently you alos need your application to be installed on your Google Drive for the embeddable widget to work. We are currently working on removing this restriction as it does not always make sense since we launched v2 of the API.

The relevant code is:

```
var shareClient = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient(rtpg.realTimeOptions.appId);
shareClient.setItemIds([rtclient.params['fileId']]);
shareClient.showSettingsDialog();
```

Is there some way to make this work with multiple accounts signed in?

Comment: Could you check your test case against www.draw.io? It's a Google Drive app with support for sharing and multiple accounts.

Comment: @Boris I am getting the same error with draw.io. Here's how to reproduce: 1) sign into multiple google accounts. 2) go to draw.io. 3) click "Connect with Google Drive". 4) Choose one of my currently signed-in Google Accounts to connect. 5) Let draw.io connect with Drive. 6) Click File > Share. 7) Share dialog loads with an animated spinner. 8) After about 30 seconds, a message saying that "sharing is not available at this time" appears. 9) I get this in Chrome dev tools: "SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12 docs.google.com/static/doclist/client/js/3362885397-v2-doclist_share.js:475"

Comment: Yeah, this looks like Google bug. Have you submitted it yet?

Comment: FWIW, there is a bug filed against this to allow passing the access token and/or user id as a hint.

Comment: Thanks @SteveBazyl. Is the bug tracker with that bug available externally?

Comment: @SteveBazyl How's that bug file doing?

Answer (score 4):

you might want to read this carefully concerning the x-frame issue:

[Google Drive API, can't open standard sharing dialog via JS (x-frame-options error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344055/google-drive-api-cant-open-standard-sharing-dialog-via-js-x-frame-options-err)

but what i think it is not possible to authenticate all the accounts at once , but a workaround maybe to `setOAuthToken` to each of them everytime you want to do so.

it is stated here in google documents that :

> Important:The setOAuthToken function allows an app to use the current
>   auth token to determine which Google account the picker uses to
>   display the files. If a user is signed into multiple Google accounts,
>   this allows the picker to display the files of the appropriate
>   authorized account.

source:

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-open

Comment: I've read that StackOverflow answer unfortunately I do not see an exposed `setOAuthToken` method on the ShareClient.

Comment: have you tried using oAuth2.0 ? https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent

Comment: I'm using oAuth2 on the backend. The user is already authenticated against a specific account too. It's just I hit a roadblock when using ShareClient

Comment: ok have a look at this please : https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php

Comment: we agree that you cant use multiple accounts at once , but as i said we can use that php example to pass the token from one account to another.

Comment: well you dont have any other work around that is a google restriction , good luck finding the answer .

Comment: You're right, that's probably a bit harsh. The bounty *does* say that I'll accept a workaround and this is it.

Comment: anyway i was just trying to help

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue - ShareClient doesn't show up if using multiple accounts. I couldn't use this workaround, because ShareClient doesn't have setOAuthToken method.

Comment: @bitle maybe you should create a new question then.

Answer (score 2):

We just recently added a `setOAuthToken()` method to the `ShareClient` that allows you to specify which user the dialog should use. More details in the Drive SDK [release notes](https://developers.google.com/drive/release-notes#multi-login_support_in_the_sharing_dialog).

Comment: Damn you guys; I just want to use an script in my own damn document and now I got to fix code that I didn't create. Google always creating things and they breaking them for every one that used them.