# Google API Detect Multiple Account Login

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Google have an issue with their document [sharing dialog](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing#launching_the_google_drive_sharing_dialog_in_your_app) in that if a user is signed into multiple accounts it will spin and then report "...unavailable at this time..."

This has been reported in stackoverflow e.g.
[Can't get Google Drive API share dialog to work when signed into multiple accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664523/cant-get-google-drive-api-share-dialog-to-work-when-signed-into-multiple-accoun) and Google is planning a fix.

In the interim I am trying to find a method that can reliably detect if a user is logged into multiple accounts, enabling me to only show a sharing option when the dialog will work. Can any one suggest a way to detect multiple logins?

Answer (score 2):

You can't check if a user is logged into multiple accounts unless you authorize each account via OAuth (which isn't an acceptable approach). Here is my **horrible** workaround for this bug.

*DISCLAIMER:*
1. This is a `setTimeout` watcher :(
2. This relies on the fact the user is using an English locale :( :(
3. This relies on the fact that text is exactly: `Sorry, sharing is unavailable at this time. Please try again later.` :( :( :(

```js
var TIME_LIMIT_SECONDS = 35;
var errorTimer = null;
var startTime = null;
// Call this function after you call showSettingsDialog()
function watchForErrors() {
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
    startErrorTimer();
};
// Starts the error check
function startErrorTimer() {
    errorTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        var $test = $(".dcs-cd-dcs-c-dcs-eb").filter(function () { return $(this).text().trim() === "Sorry, sharing is unavailable at this time. Please try again later."; });
        if ($test.length) {
            // Message detected...do something
            console.log("Error Found!");
            // Close the share dialog
            $("span.dcs-cd-dcs-c-dcs-k-dcs-bc[role='button']").trigger("click");
            return;
        }
        if ((new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000 < TIME_LIMIT_SECONDS) {
            // No errors detected. Could be a success at this point
            startErrorTimer();
        } else {
           // No errors found after 35 seconds - probably a success?
            console.log("Timeout - Success?");
        }
    }, 200);
};
```

What I do is show a success message behind the share dialog as soon as I call `showSettingsDialog()`. If the method fails, I close the share dialog. If the method succeeds, the user will close the dialog & see my success message.

Comment: Ouch that is indeed... horrible. Quite possibly the depths I'll have to go to though. I need to consider this - thank you very much for posting.